Getting more information about error logs
I have a problem to get the right information about an error when trying to insert a row in a table.
Let's have an example.
So we create a test table that has four (04) columns.
drop table test_tab;
create table test_tab
(
var1 number(2)  ,
var2 number(2)  ,
var3 number(1)  ,
var4 number(2)
);

Then, we create a log table to log errors when inserted rows doesn't match the table requirements (columns size).
drop table test_tab_err_log;
begin
dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'test_tab'
, err_log_table_name => 'test_tab_err_log');
end;
/

Then, we try to insert a row to that table and violate the third column requirements.
SQL> insert into test_tab
  2  select 0,0,25,0
  3  from dual
  4  log errors
  5  into test_tab_err_log ('INSERT')
  6  reject limit unlimited
  7  ;

0 rows created.

The problem is, when we fetch about the rows that caused an error, the returned message doesn't tell us which column provokes the error.
SQL> column ora_err_mesg$ format a80
SQL> select ora_err_number$, ora_err_mesg$ from test_tab_err_log;

ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ ORA_ERR_MESG$
--------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           1438 ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

 real: 15
SQL> 

So, is there a way or a workaround to know that the var3 column has been violated.
Thanks in advance,

Hi! You might have considered using SQLERRM|| CHR(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace

@BarbarosÖzhan You may wish to expand upon that because I cannot see how that will help fiddle as when using LOG ERRORS the output will be ORA-0000: normal, successful completion because the INSERT completed and all the errors were "succesfully" logged.

I haven't really used much of dbms_errlog, but what I usually use for logs of the exceptions is:
dbms_output.put_line('Exception: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack(),1,4000));
dbms_output.put_line('Backtrace: ' ||SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace,1,4000));

reference

log errors into unfortunately only records the errored row and column values and error number. It does not record the line and column in the full error stack as the accompanying ORA-06550 that you get in the normal exception thrown when you don't log errors:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 8:
That's unfortunate, because with this info you can find out the exact position in your SQL where the error was located, and from that you can figure out which column it was.
Nor will dbms_utility.format_error_stack() help, because this is only for use in PL/SQL, and a SQL embedded in PL/SQL will only report its starting line position within the PL/SQL program, not the line and column within the SQL like standalone SQL error reporting does.
However, given that log errors into does show you the column values, simple inspection should show a human where the issue is, assuming you know the datatype limits and constraints on each column. If you see a three digit number for a column limited to two digits, you know that's what caused the problem. So, you may be trying to solve a problem that doesn't need solving.
Note: Do be aware that log errors is intended more for debugging purposes rather than normal architectural use. Under normal circumstances we generally want SQL errors to throw exceptions and abort the work being done so that SQL operations are properly atomic. You wouldn't want to try to insert 10 rows (e.g. with an INSERT SELECT) and have only 9 succeed and go on your merry way as if all was well. Using this as a normal programming technique breaks a few important database concepts so should be generally avoided.
